# How to handle request disconnect in node/express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I have an express/node app and I would like to capture when there is an unexpected interruption in the connection. I tried the following:

```
req.on('close', function () {
  //this captures the browser/tab close scenarios 
})
```

My code does not work in the following scenerios:

- Wifi is disconnected
- Device shuts down due to lack of power

Is there an event handler that could be leveraged in these scenarios?

Comment: No, not really, you'd have to poll the client to see if it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sockets to accomplish this. [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) is popular.

```
var io = require('socket.io')({
  'port': 8000,
  'heartbeat interval': 2000,
  'heartbeat timeout' : 3000
});
io.listen(server);

var app_socket = io.of('/foo');
app_socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // BROWSER CONNECTED

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    // BROWSER DISCONNECTED
  });
});
```

The disconnect event will fire whenever the client loses connection. To connect on the client side it would look like this:

```
<script media="all" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('/foo');
  socket.on("connect", function(){
    // CONNECTED TO SERVER
  });
</script>
```

Comment: in this particular use case i'm dealing with streaming data which is broadcasted via SSE. Fundamentally i have a streaming end point which delivers response in text/event-stream and whenever the stream is stopped unexpectedly in any of the scenarios that i mentioned earlier then i need to perform an action at that moment.